# Compressing images before uploading them to s3 bucket

Tags: python, flask

I would like to compress the user´s profile image before uploading them to my s3 bucket. I have a flask app.

This is my code:

```
@app.route("/profile", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def profile():
        if request.method == "POST":
            user_id = session["user_id"]
            if request.files['photo']:
                filename = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
                ## here should go the code to compress the image
                s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
                s3.Bucket('mybucketname').upload_file("static/img/" + filename, filename)
                row = User.query.filter_by(user_id = user_id).first()
                row.img_url = filename
                updated_filename = row.img_url
                db.session.commit()
```

Im new to python. I tried implementing one with PIL, but failed to adapt the code from tutorials. I would be grateful if you guys could help me out.

Comment: "*I tried implementing one with PIL, but failed to adapt the code from tutorials*": Show your attempts at doing the compression and what went wrong with it (ex. Did you get errors?). This would give others an idea of what you expect for the compression.

Comment: Is your objective to save space? Saving JPEGs at a lower quality level might do that. The trade-off is how much money you'll save, which you can estimate with a few experiments and a spreadsheet, vs. how much you'll annoy your users, which is rather harder to experiment with up front.

Comment: @GinoMempin The images I am trying to save are from mobile phones, and the space of most of them is at least 2mb. I was looking for a function to save space without losing quality. I struggled using Image.open(), but in general I couldnt understand how to adapt it.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith Yes, i want to save space, but not for money. This images will be imported to the users contact app as a vcf file. If I use this images that cost a lot of space, it makes the entire vcf file big (about 3mb) and the importation of the contact fails because the file is too big.